# What's This Syntax All About?

Tags: javascript

These are the first few lines in the MicrosoftAjax.debug.js file.

What are they doing with the syntax? Specifically line 3.

```
Function.__typeName = 'Function';
Function.__class = true;
Function.createCallback = function Function$createCallback(method, context) {
```

Comment: They're setting some properties on the `Function` constructor. What about it?

Comment: btw the function literal in line 3 is a named function expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is ordinary code which happens to have a `$` character in a function name.

The expression `function Function$createCallback(method, context) { ... }` is a named function expression; it evaluates to a function named `Function$createCallback`.
Unlike many languages, the `$` character is perfectly legal in a Javascript identifier (see jQuery), so this is a normal function with a somewhat unusual name.

The code assigns that function to create a `createCallback` property on the `Function` object.
(The property happens to be a function; Javascript functions are no different from variables)

Comment: What is the benefit of assigning a named vs. anonymous function to that property?

Comment: @Šime Vidas: I was just about to post that same article. :o)